# How to store the string values into an array in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have one parameter every time it comes from the request object in a standard order,I want to store that string into an array by splitting `\`for that i am using explode function it's throwing an error,please help me to explode with backslash

```
$obj = "App\Http\Data\User";
$array = explode("\",$obj);
```

Comment: You need `"\\"` to encode a backslash in a string.` So, `$array = explode("\\",$obj);`

Comment: A single \ is an escape character. so `$array = explode("\\",$obj);`

Comment: or use single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$obj = "App\Http\Data\User";
$array = explode("\\",$obj);


print_r($array);
```

example [here](https://paiza.io/projects/hvvNS5btM9P8T8eznyZZPQ)